# confidence intervals for fixed effects with reML

Tags: bootstrap, glmm, nonparametric

I am trying to asses wheter certain effects are significant in my mixed model.
First I tried the confint function with the profile method and the Wald method. Both are somewhat similaire, now I want to perform a parametric bootstrap and I was wondering why isn't it possible to do this with a reML model? the package I use: PBmodcomp sets reML to false.

This: [Kenward-Roger and REML](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/231900/kenward-roger-and-reml) didn't really help me further, why is it nonsenical to use a reML model, I thought reML was needed to get BLUE's?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a fairly subtle distinction here between fitting *reduced* models, which is what `PBmodcomp()` does and what you want to do to get p-values etc., and fitting models with varying values of a focal parameter, which is what `confint()` and friends do.

- Fitting reduced and full models (that differ in their fixed effects) via REML and comparing them **does not work**; that is, if we set one of the parameters to zero and refit, we get a structurally different model that doesn't correspond to the full model we started with
- Taking a REML model and re-evaluating/refitting it if we change the values of the focal (and other) parameters but *don't set them specifically to zero* is fine; this doesn't change the structure of the model. (Although I see that we *do* convert the REML fit to ML when profiling over the fixed effects in `lme4` ... hmmm ...)

In particular, if you're looking to compute *confidence intervals* for a `[g]lmer` fit by parametric bootstrapping, you should use `confint(., method="boot")` rather than `pbkrtest::PBmodcomp`. This doesn't actually do anything with a reduced model; rather, it simulates values from the *full* model and re-fits.